# SagePay with Laravel, Route issue

Tags: php, laravel-4, opayo

Im integrating Sagepay and after successful payment it returns a url like so:

```
 /success?crypt=@4672799fb6f902806caba4
```

So how can i reflect this in my routes file.

I currently have:

```
Route::get('success', function(){
return 'Success';
});
```

But doesn't work, so what should I need in the routes file to achieve this callback?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that it is issuing a GET request, the callback may be a POST.

Try:

```
Route::all('success', function(){
    return 'Success';
});
```

Comment: It is definitely a GET using Sage Pay Form.